# Javascript to detect when a page has loaded in another window in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, loading, detect

I was wondering what the best way was to detect when a page has finished loading, where the page in question is in a different tab or window, ... and where page to be loaded could be any page on the web and is not under my control.

I am using Firefox only and I don't mind if the solution requires a Firefox extension or Grease Monkey script (I have already added the configuration/commands to allow access to pages from different domains).

The code below shows an attempt. It sometimes detects when the initial page has loaded but when I press 'submit' to reload a new page into the other window, it doesn't detect it.

Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    currentPageObj = window.open("http://www.bbc.co.uk", "currentPage");

    currentPageObj.addEventListener("load", function(){alert("loaded")}, false);

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="http://www.example.com" target="currentPage">
         <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are the two pages coming from the same domain?

Answer (score 1):

In the other page just have an onload event handler which calls a method in the parent window (`window.opener`) to do what you want. e.g. in the child page:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed)  {
     window.opener.childLoaded();
  }
}, false);
```

And have childLoad do what you want in the parent window. (Note: it might be best to keep a reference to the window you want to deal with e.g. initialise `var parentWindow = window;` because when you call between windows this can get confusing.)

Comment: Thanks andrewmu, but I forgot to mention that in the other window I'm loading a page from a different domain that I dont have control of and therefore I cant edit this page.

Comment: Ok.. that is tricky then.  Unless you do some clever proxying through your server and insert the appropriate response into the page on it's way back. E.g. put the above into a script tag that gets insert before the </body> of the response before you send it to the browser.

Comment: What if the other page is not HTML, e.g. if it is a PDF file?  Any suggestions how the parent window can know when it has completed loading?